# Liquid UI Flutter Button getter _theme was called on null

Tags: forms, flutter

I am new to Flutter and Liquid UI, I am trying to build a form but examples taken from Liquid Ui documentation fail in my app, in particular cannot insert any Button, I get this error:
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building LButtonGroup(dirty):
The getter '_theme' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: _theme

The relevant error-causing widget was:
LButtonGroup

Here is my code:

```
final _manager = LFormManager();
....

LForm(
                manager: _manager,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    LTextFormField(
                      name: "email", 
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your email',
                      ),
                      initialValue: 'xyz@xyz.com',
                      validators: [
                    LRequiredValidator(),
                    LEmailValidator(
                        invalidMessage: "Please enter correct email address")
                  ], 
                    ),
                    LButtonGroup(
                      children: [
                        LFlatButton.text(
                          text: 'Left',
                          type: LElementType.dark,
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        LFlatButton.text(
                          text: 'Middle',
                          type: LElementType.dark,
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        LFlatButton.text(
                          text: 'Right',
                          type: LElementType.dark,
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I ran into this issue sometime ago and here's how I solved it.

Wrap your top level `MaterialApp` with `LiquidApp`

```
import 'package:liquid_ui/liquid_ui.dart';
void main() async {

runApp(LiquidApp(materialApp: MaterialApp(home: WelcomePage()));
    
}
```